# Redmine - Display commit message on both issue details and email notification

Tags: redmine

How a commit message can be displayed on both issue details and email notification? Regarding the issue notification, I know I've had it already up and running, but it stop working without apparent reason. For now, the only information which is displayed regarding the commit is the related changeset in the History section.

Thanks in advance for the help,
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I think I already know which the problem was; the project in question is a sub-project from a main project and thus, is not possible to associated each revision with a specific issue.